# Join dataframes with list field

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-structured-streaming

I'm using structured streaming with pyspark, and I'm reading from a kafka topic a key, which is an integer, and a value, which is a coma separated list of integers

I'm trying to make a join of this dataframe with another dataframe that I get from MongoDB. I could also mke a filter based on the values of the kafka dataframe, that are present in the column "id" of the MongoDB dataframe (though I don't know if the concept is also correct)

kafka dataframe:

| key | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2,9,7 |

MongoDB dataframe

| name | id |
| --- | --- |
| camp_1 | 1 |
| camp_2 | 9 |
| camp_3 | 5 |
| camp_4 | 7 |
| camp_5 | 2 |

So, the result should be

| name | id |
| --- | --- |
| camp_5 | 2 |
| camp_2 | 9 |
| camp_4 | 7 |

I'm thinking in a join since I've been unable to iterate over the values of the list in the "value" field of the kafka dataframe

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use explode and then join

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode

kafkaData = [("1", [2, 7, 9])]
kafkaDf = spark.createDataFrame(kafkaData, schema=["key", "Value"])

mongoData = [("Camp_1", 1), ("Camp_2", 9), ("Camp_3", 5), ("Camp_4", 7), ("Camp_5", 2)]
mongoDf = spark.createDataFrame(mongoData, schema=["name", "id"])

kafkaDfExploded = kafkaDf.select(explode("Value").alias("id"))
kafkaDfExploded.join(mongoDf, "id", "left").select("name", "id").show()
```

output:

```
+------+---+
|  name| id|
+------+---+
|Camp_4|  7|
|Camp_2|  9|
|Camp_5|  2|
+------+---+
```

You may add order by if it is relevant for you, you may also broadcast one of df if you know its going to be small.

If your list 2, 7, 9 is not an array but string you can first split it, then rest will be similar

Comment: this seems like a good solution, but since I'm using structured streaming I'm getting this error in the line that triggers the join: `.AnalysisException: Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start();`